# Como puedo guardar los emails de mi website?

Tags: php, html

estoy creando mi web en html y css, he hecho un formulario para que los usuarios puedan suscribirse a mi newsletter, pero no se realmente como guardar los emails, ni cual sería la mejor herramienta para hacerlo,  que recomiendan ustedes?.

Comment: estas usando algun lenguaje de backend y algun gestor de bases de datos?

Comment: Aún no, solo estoy realizando la la parte visual de la web. @AlfredoPaz

Comment: necesitas usar por ejemplo php y mysql de otro modo con lo que usas sera imposible hacer lo que quieres

Comment: Hola Eduardo Canale, tal y como está redactada la pregunta es muy amplia y se basa principalmente en opiniones. Para que la publicación sea reabierta, hazla más concreta, añadiendo detalles como lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento (o lo que tienes en mente implementar) o requerimientos más específicos. Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que hubo Eduardo si no sabes cómo hacerlo usa una herramienta externa para recolectar información sin necesidad de hacer mucho código. Podrías utilizar

https://try.airtable.com/forms
https://www.typeform.com
https://www.google.com/intl/es/forms/about/

Nada más tienes que ver cuál sería la mejor estrategia para integrar ese servicio a tu sitio web.